# Invoke a message on Cannot read property 'faceId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling an API. On a certain condition it returns a error

`Cannot read property 'faceId' of undefined`

On this condition, I wish to `console.log("no result")`, I am unable to catch this condition, below is my function -

I tried with `response.length` but in case of undefined it doesn't return anything. I also tried with `faceid === undefined` but again that is also not working. How do I catch this error state?

```
function detect(imageURL){
  console.log(imageURL);
  var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&recognitionModel=recognition_02&returnRecognitionModel=false&detectionModel=detection_01",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "ocp-apim-subscription-key": "f4446c96213wwwds51093ce12d558",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "host": "centralindia.api.cognitive.microsoft.com",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "106bce66-4936-231-5835-c3ae443433e2"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data" : `{ "url" : "${imageURL}" }`

}

$.ajax(settings).done(async function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  console.log(response[0].faceId);
  var faceid = response[0].faceId;
  var reslength = response.length;
  console.log(reslength);
  if (faceid === null){
    console.log("faceid is null");
  }
  if(faceid === undefined){
    console.log("faceid is undefined");
  }
  document.getElementById("show_progress").innerHTML = "2";
  await identify(faceid);
});
}
```

### Edit 1

console.log of `response` when it returns value

[image]

### Edit 2

Error comes on this line `console.log(response[0].faceId);`

If no error, I get the value.

Also note, before the error, console.log(response) is [] in `console.log`.

Comment: is `ocp-apim-subscription-key` sensitive?  Make sure change the value of secrets before posting!

Comment: also what gets output from `console.log(response);` it's likely not an array and doesn't have a property `0` so that `response[0] === undefined`

Comment: i have already changed the sensitive key values, see edit::1 of my question, attached image of response when it return the result

Comment: error comes on this line `console.log(response[0].faceId);` , 

If no error, i get the value

Comment: So just to confirm, you're saying that in the error scenario, `console.log(response[0])` is NOT returning `"undefined"` and `console.log(response[0].faceId)` is throwing that error?

Comment: In error state `response[0].faceId` and `response[0]` is not returning `undefined`  ,  yes `console.log(response[0].faceId)` is throwing the error

Comment: also note before the error, console.log(response) is [] in `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

The thing that is undefined is `response[0]`.

You need this to catch it:

```
if (response[0] === undefined) {
  console.log("response[0] is undefined");
}
```

Comment: response[0] , response, response[0].faceId   nothing worked

Comment: So when you do console.log(response[0]), what is the result?

Comment: see edit::1 of my question, attached image of response when it return the result, response[0].faceid gives me the value

Comment: error comes on this line `console.log(response[0].faceId);` , 

If no error, i get the value